# How to Restrict object creation based on Arraylist size

Tags: java, arrays

In the below code if **recordset.size()** is **Zero** it is creating one Employee object. So is there any way to restrict so that if **recordset.size()** > Zero only it should need to create Employee object.

```
ArrayList recordSet = new ArrayList();
//fetching data from database and keeping that many number of records in **recordSet**
.....
...DB related code...
.....
recordset.add(records); //'records' contain details of particular number of rows
//Based on number of returned rows from database object is creating
Employee[] emp = new Employee[recordset.size()];
```

Comment: Does that even compile?  The types on the second line are wrong.

Comment: Why can't you just use an `if` statement to check the size of `recordset`?

Comment: If i use 'if' statement as per my requirement  it will throw NullPointerException

Comment: Only if `recordset` is null.

Comment: recordset won't be null due to the first line.

Answer (score 5):

```
Employee emp = new Employee[recordSet.size()];
```

This is syntactically wrong and gives compilation error. I think you are trying to achieve this.

```
Employee[] emp = new Employee[recordSet.size()];
```

This will create an array of objects as you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

you should take care of the record**S**et variable's case , then only it will be compiled.

```
Employee[] emp = new Employee[recordSet.size()];
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are trying to find is this condition:

```
if(recordset!=null && recordset.size()>0)
```

Also since you are creating an array on the right hand side,

```
new Employee[recordset.size()];
```

you should correct your left hand side to:

```
Employee[] emp = new Employee[recordset.size()];
```